# How to save multiple check box into database in rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I want to save multiple check box category[] into database :-

```
<label><%= f.check_box :category,{class: 'chk'},1,0%>Apple</label>
<label><%= f.check_box :category,{class: 'chk'},1,0%>Orange</label>
<label><%= f.check_box :category,{class: 'chk'},1,0%>Banana</label>
```

[Here my create form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiRPK.png)
[Edit form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRTAz.png)

[controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVF6t.png)

[database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9AHU.png)

Comment: What is your problem? If you want to store something in a database, just do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a :multiple option, if that's what you need? It's hard to understand exactly what you want

```
    check_box("puppy", "commands", {:multiple => true}, "sit", nil)
    check_box("puppy", "commands", {:multiple => true}, "fetch", nil)
    check_box("puppy", "commands", {:multiple => true}, "roll_over", nil)
```

Further examples here: https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/check_box

Comment: Your solution can save data with multiple array. I also would like to know if I checked Apple and Orange in registration form, it also checked Apple and Orange in edit form untile I change checkbox uncheck.